# JS console error shows Extjs trying to make a GET request for a class as if it was a file

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Sorry if the title isn't the best.

I'm roughing out a test project in Extjs 6. I have a viewmodel class that uses a store called `customers`:

```
Ext.define('ChildSessionBinding.view.main.ChildSessionModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.binding.childsession',

    requires:[
        'Ext.data.Store',
        'ChildSessionBinding.model.Customer'
    ],

    stores:{
        customers:{
            model: 'ChildSessionBinding.model.Customer',
            autoLoad: true,
            session: true
        }
    }
});
```

The model it requires has hard coded test data in it:

```
Ext.define('ChildSessionBinding.model.Customer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'phone', type: 'auto' }
    ],

    data:[
        {name: 'test', phone: '12345'}
    ]
});
```

And the view that uses the ViewModel is just a panel that shows a simple grid:

```
Ext.define('ChildSessionBinding.view.main.ChildSession', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    xtype: 'binding-child-session',

    title: 'Binding Child Session Demo',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    viewModel: {
        type: 'binding.childsession'
    },

    controller: 'binding.childsession',

    session: true,

    items:[
        {
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'grid',
            bind: '{customers}',
            columns:[
                {
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 1,
                    text: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    dataIndex: 'phone',
                    flex: 1,
                    text: 'Phone'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                    width: 90,
                    widget: {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Edit',
                        handler: 'onEditCustomerClick'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

When I load this in the browser, the grid does not load. I popped open the javascript console and saw that it was trying to make a get request to the server using the model's fully qualified name:

[image: wtf]

I've compared it to [the kitchen sink example I'm trying to duplicate](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-child-session) as well as other viewmodel stores that I've created in other projects and I don't see anything that would cause this.

Also, to rule out any project file structure questions, here's the folder/file structure:

[image: folder and file structure]

## EDIT

Here's the stack trace from the javascript console:

[image: the javascript console stack trace]

Anyone see the problem?

Comment: I have seen this issue last year in ExtJS 4.2.1, I wonder whether I can remember what the cause was. It was my fault, I can say that for sure. Give me a day to think about it (and the Stack Trace from your console, please!).

Comment: Sure thing and thanks. I'll add the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the data in your store, not in your model. Model doesn't have a [`data property`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Model).

Comment: *facepalm* of course! Moved it over and it worked. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: NP! We all have those days :P

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used much of Ext 5 or 6 but I think I have seen this error on Ext 4.  If a required class is undefined during the time of a class definition Ext will try to load a file with that name at the root of your application.  I think that Ext should be throwing an error here by default instead of trying to load a file since I assume that most applications are not set up to handle this.

The fix would be to have `ChildSessionBinding.model.Customer` defined and executed before you load `ChildSessionBinding.view.main.ChildSessionModel` or have your application be able to load that file where Ext expects it to be.

Comment: Hmm, I get what you're suggesting, but I'm not sure how I would implement that within the sencha framework (and why it's not doing it itself). I tried adding the `models:['Customer']` config to my `Application.js` file thinking that would load it before all of the other classes, but that didn't seem to do it.

Comment: Yeah you would have to read how to do it with the sencha tools, I try to avoid using them when I can.